# Feedback on ArrayList using OOPs

Tags: java, object-oriented

Please review my code for the problem statement below. Many Thanks.

> You job is to create a simple banking application.
>
> There should be a Bank class:
>
> - It should have an `ArrayList`of `Branche`s
> - Each Branch should have an `ArrayList`of `Customer`  s
> - The Customer class should have an `ArrayList`of `Double`s (transactions)
>
> Customer:
>
> - Name, and the `ArrayList` of `Double`s.
>
> Branch:
>
> - Need to be able to add a new customer and initial transaction amount.
> - Also needs to add additional transactions for that customer/branch
>
> Bank:
>
> - Add a new branch
> - Add a customer to that branch with initial transaction
> - Add a transaction for an existing customer for that branch

Show a list of customers for a particular branch and optionally a list of their transactions Demonstration autoboxing and unboxing in your code.

```
import java.lang.Double;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer{

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Double> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Customer(String name,double initialTransaction){
        this.name = name;
        this.transactions.add(Double.valueOf(initialTransaction));    
    }

    public String getCustomerName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public Double getInitialTransaction(){
        return this.transactions.get(0);
    }
        
    public void addTransaction(double transaction){
        this.transactions.add(Double.valueOf(transaction));
    }

    public String getCustomerDetails(){
        return getCustomerName()+"\t\t\t"+transactions;
    }
}

import java.lang.Double;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Branch{

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Customer> customers;

    public Branch(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.customers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public String getBranchName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){
        if(customer!=null){
            if(!searchCustomer(customer)){
                this.customers.add(customer);
                //System.out.println("Customer with name "+customer.getCustomerName()+" added to branch "+getBranchName());
            }else{
                //System.out.println("Customer with name "+customer.getCustomerName()+" already present in branch "+getBranchName());
            }            
        }else{
            //System.out.println("Customer with null values entered!!!");
        }
    }

    public void addTransaction(Customer customer,double transaction){
        if(customer!=null || transaction<=0.0){
            if(searchCustomer(customer)){
                this.customers.get(this.customers.indexOf(customer)).addTransaction(transaction);
                //System.out.println("Transaction of "+transaction+" added in account of Customer with name "+customer.getCustomerName());
            }else{
                //System.out.println("Customer with name "+customer.getCustomerName()+" not present in branch "+getBranchName()+". Please add the customer.");
            }            
        }else{
            //System.out.println("Customer with null values or no transaction entered!!!");
        }
    }
    
    public void printCustomerList(){
        System.out.println("Customer Name \t\t Transactions");
        for(Customer cx:customers){
            System.out.println(cx.getCustomerDetails());
        }
    }
    
    public boolean searchCustomer(Customer customer){
        for(int i=0;i<this.customers.size();i++){
            if(this.customers.get(i).equals(customer)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}

import java.lang.Double;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bank{

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Branch> branches;
    
    public Bank(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.branches = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public String getBankName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void addBranch(Branch branch,Customer customer){
        if(branch!=null){
            if(!searchBranch(branch)){
                branch.addCustomer(customer);
                this.branches.add(branch);
                System.out.println("Customer with name "+customer.getCustomerName()+" with an initialTransaction of "+customer.getInitialTransaction().doubleValue()+" is added to Branch with name "+branch.getBranchName()+" of bank "+getBankName());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Branch with name "+branch.getBranchName()+" already present");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Branch with null values entered!!!");
        }
    }
    
    public void addTransaction(Branch branch, Customer customer,double transaction){
        if(branch!=null || customer!=null){
            if(searchBranch(branch) && branch.searchCustomer(customer)){
                branch.addTransaction(customer,transaction);
                System.out.println("Transaction of "+transaction+" added in account of Customer with name "+customer.getCustomerName()+" under branch "+branch.getBranchName()+" of bank "+getBankName());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Customer with name "+customer.getCustomerName()+" not present in branch "+branch.getBranchName()+". Please add the customer.");
            }    
        }else{
            System.out.println("Branch or Customer with null values entered!!!");
        }
    }
    
    public void printCustomersOfBranch(Branch branch){
        if(branch!=null){
            if(searchBranch(branch)){
                branch.printCustomerList();
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Branch with null values entered!!!");
        }
    }
    
    private boolean searchBranch(Branch branch){
        for(int i=0;i<branches.size();i++){
            if(this.branches.get(i).equals(branch)){
                return true;
            }                
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public class BankTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        Bank pnb = new Bank("Punjab National Bank");
        
        Branch peachtree = new Branch("Peach Tree");
        
        Branch rodeodrive = new Branch("Rodeo Drive");
        
        Branch goodearth = new Branch("Good Earth");
        
        Customer harsh = new Customer("Harsh",0.5);
        
        Customer nidhi = new Customer("Nidhi",600.75);
        
        Customer yuv = new Customer("Yuv",1785.95);
        
        pnb.addBranch(peachtree,harsh);
        
        pnb.addBranch(rodeodrive,nidhi);
        
        pnb.addBranch(goodearth,yuv);
        
        pnb.printCustomersOfBranch(peachtree);
        
        pnb.printCustomersOfBranch(rodeodrive);
        
        pnb.printCustomersOfBranch(goodearth);
        
        pnb.addTransaction(peachtree,harsh,500.60);
        
        pnb.addTransaction(rodeodrive,nidhi,150000.70);
        
        pnb.addTransaction(goodearth,yuv,121798.12);
        
        pnb.printCustomersOfBranch(peachtree);
        
        pnb.printCustomersOfBranch(rodeodrive);
        
        pnb.printCustomersOfBranch(goodearth);


    }

}
```

Comment: Do you expect some specifc remarks on the code. About the perfs, structure, maitainability, style, .. ?

Comment: Importing `java.lang.Double` is unnecessary, all of `java.lang.*` is imported by default.

Comment: @gervais.b Well I am a starter(10th time), so any feedback would be helpful. Also would like a suggestion to concentrate solely on gaining conceptual understanding or also focus more on style, structure, maintainability because I haven't come across all these in the course I am following.

Comment: @markspace Duly noted. Also I noted that instead of calling Double.valueOf, I could directly pass the double value which will be autoboxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Demonstration autoboxing and unboxing in your code.

You can then remove the calls to `Double#valueOf(double)` and 
`Double#doubleValue():doube`. Then you can replace `Double` with `double`
when applicable (return of public methods).

**Searching items in list**

At some times you are using `List#indexOf(Object):int` but in other places, you 
are looping on the list to test the equality of an item (`searchCustomer`, 
`searchBranch`).

The Javadoc of [`ArrayList#indexOf(Object):int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) states that :

> returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))

So you can easily replace your loops in your search methods by 
`return theList.indexOf(something) > -1`

But there is still a better way to check if a list contains an item: [`ArrayList#contains(Object):boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

**Naming**

Based on the previous comment, you could also rename your `searchXyz` methods to 
`contains` or another more meaningful name. This may be a cultural issue but, 
most of the time when "we" (BE_fr devs) read `search`, "we" expect to receive a 
collection of found objects.

**Complexity**

Instead of nesting your `if`s like in `Branch#addTransaction(..)`  you can *fail quickly* :

```
if ( customer==null || transaction <= 0.0 ) {
   // fail
} else if ( !contains(customer) ) {
   // fail 
} else {
   // This is fine
}
```

If you rely on `Exception` for your failure you can also reduce a bit the nesting 
of your method :

```
if ( isThisInvalid(..) ) {
    throw new InvalidOperation(..);   
}    

// This is fine
```

The less path/branches you have in your code, the better it is. That's also why 
I introduced a validation method, to move the validations rules outside of the 
business code.

**Encapsulation**

Not all your methods have to be public, try to mark as much as possible as `private`
or *package protected* to reduce your public API.

**Separation of concerns**

Most of the time, for maintainability and testability concerns, you try extract 
concerns in different classes. That's why there are some popular high-level patterns 
like *MVC*, *MVP*, ...

In your case you could move the printing to a dedicated class that will be 
responsible to gather, format and print values from your model.

---

Here are some excerpt of how your final code may looks like:

```
class Branch {
    private final ArrayList<Customer> customers;
    private final String name;

    public Branch(String name) {
        this.customers = new ArrayList<>();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBranchName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return new ArrayList<>(customers);
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        if (!isValidCustomer(customer)) {
            throw new InvalidCustomerException( customer);
        }
        customers.add(customer);
    }

    private boolean isValidCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return  customer!=null &&
                !contains(customer);
    }

    public void addTransaction(Customer customer, double transaction) {
        if (!isValidaTransaction(customer, transaction)) {
            throw new InvalidTransactionException(customer, transaction);
        }
        getCustomer(customer).addTransaction(transaction);
        this.customers.get(this.customers.indexOf(customer)).addTransaction(transaction);
    }

    private boolean isValidaTransaction(Customer customer, double transaction) {
        return  customer!=null &&
                transaction <= 0.0 &&
                contains(customer);
    }

    private boolean contains(Customer customer) {
        return customers.contains(customer);
    }

    private Customer getCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return customers.get(customers.indexOf(customer));
    }
}  

class BranchCustomersPrinter implements Consumer<Bank> {    
    private final PrintWriter output;

    @Override
    public void accept(Bank bank) {
        Branch branch = bank.getBranch(branch);
        output.append("Customer Name \t\t Transactions");
        branch.getCustomers().forEach(customer ->
                output.append(customer.getCustomerName())
                      .append("\t\t")
                      .append(customer.getTransactions())
                );
        output.flush();
    }
}   

Bank bank = ...
bank.print(new BranchCustomersPrinter(..));
```

---

Note; Your validation in `Branch#addTransaction(..)` seems to be buggy. It will 
accept a `null` customer with a transaction bigger than `0`. It will also never 
accept a positive transaction.

---

Note; Java uses references and since your program will always run in memory you 
don't need to get an item from the list to update his values.

```
Customer c1 = new Customer("One", 10);
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(c1);

c1.addTransaction(5); // Is the same as :
list.get(list.indexOf(c1)).addTransaction(5);
```

But most of the time; you have to save and retrieve the customer from a persistent 
storage.

This is also why `list.contains(c1)` returns `true`. Because it is effectively the 
same "object"; doing the same with two customers having the same properties will 
not work:

```
Customer c1 = new Customer("Customer", 10);    
Customer c2 = new Customer("Customer", 10);

c1.equals(c2); // false
```

But I guess that you will learn the subtleties of object references and `equals` 
soon.

Comment: Doesn't this accomplish the same. Please correct me if I am wrong.

 getCustomer(customer).addTransaction(transaction);
        this.customers.get(this.customers.indexOf(customer)).addTransaction(transaction);

Comment: It depends of how ‘getCustomer’ is implemented. But it can be the same yes. However ‘getSomething().doAnother()’ is not a good idea because it expose your implementation details. It is better to do ‘doAnother(Something on)’ so that you can change the may you store your objects. Read a bit on encapsulation to know more.